# regex - check url does not have an extension

Tags: javascript, regex

I need urls without extension for performing some logic in my code.

url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.gif

I tried the following and I am able to match the value after last slash.

```
/[^\/]*$/
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/**ask** 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/**ask.gif**

How to check the url value after last slash has an extension or not in regular expression?

Comment: Try this `\.\w+$`

Comment: For `gif`, you can use `url.endsWith('.gif')`.

Comment: Thanks @Tushar 

/\.\w+$/.test("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.gif") is giving me true now. Is it possible to negate(toggle) boolean in regex? I need false for url with extension.

Comment: Use Not operator `!/\.\w+$/.test(url)`

Answer (score 1):

```
[^\/.]*(\.\w+)?$
```

Check for first group.

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/kNrw8N/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `split('/')` method

**Name with extension**

```js
var a ='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.gif';

console.log(a.split('/').splice(0,a.split('/').length-1).join('/'))
```

**only extension**

```js
var a ='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.gif';

console.log(a.split('.').splice(0,a.split('.').length-1).join('.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
if (url.match("/$")) {
   // do this action if last part is slash
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need to check if this is really an url, you can get the extension by using this regexp:

`/\.[a-z0-9]+$/i`

This will fetch the file extension. If the regex has no match, there is no extension.

You can easily try out your regexp at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dINGxQ/2)

Let me know if this helped you!